# multiply two python arrays using a 'lookup'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

columns = ['id', 'A', 'B', 'C']
index = np.arange(3)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,4), columns=columns, index=index)

weights = {'A': 0.10, 'B': 1.00, 'C': 1.50}
```

I need to multiple the values in each 'cell' with the corresponding weight (excluding the first column). For example:

```
df.at[0,'A'] * weights['A']
df.at[0,'B'] * weights['B']
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this and have the results in a new DataFrame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df
Out[1013]: 
         id         A         B         C
0 -0.641314 -0.526509  0.225116 -1.131141
1  0.018321 -0.944734 -0.123334 -0.853356
2  0.703119  0.468857  1.038572 -1.529723

weights
Out[1026]: {'A': 0.1, 'B': 1.0, 'C': 1.5}

W = np.asarray([weights[e] for e in sorted(weights.keys())])
```

**Solution**

```
#use a matrix multiplication to apply the weights to each column
df.loc[:,['A','B','C']] *= W
df
Out[1016]: 
         id         A         B         C
0 -0.641314 -0.052651  0.225116 -1.696712
1  0.018321 -0.094473 -0.123334 -1.280034
2  0.703119  0.046886  1.038572 -2.294584
```

**Update**

If you need to keep column names flexible, I think a better way is to save column names and weights in 2 lists:

```
columns = sorted(weights.keys())
Out[1072]: ['A', 'B', 'C']

weights = [weights[e] for e in columns]
Out[1074]: [0.1, 1.0, 1.5]
```

Then you can just do it this way:

```
df.loc[:,columns] *=weights

Out[1067]: 
         id         A         B         C
0 -0.641314 -0.052651  0.225116 -1.696712
1  0.018321 -0.094473 -0.123334 -1.280034
2  0.703119  0.046886  1.038572 -2.294584
```

**A oneliner solution:**

```
df.loc[:,sorted(weights.keys())] *=[weights[e] for e in sorted(weights.keys())]

df
Out[1089]: 
         id         A         B         C
0 -0.641314 -0.052651  0.225116 -1.696712
1  0.018321 -0.094473 -0.123334 -1.280034
2  0.703119  0.046886  1.038572 -2.294584
```

Comment: Does this assume the weights array is in the same order as the df columns? In my actual data, they won't be, so I need a way to lookup the corresponding weight

Comment: @weights is not an array, it is a `dict`

Comment: Please see my udpates to see if this is what you are after.

Answer (score 3):

I think simpliest is create `Series` from `dict` which can align indexes with column names:

```
print (df)
         id         A         B         C
0 -0.641314 -0.526509  0.225116 -1.131141
1  0.018321 -0.944734 -0.123334 -0.853356
2  0.703119  0.468857  1.038572 -1.529723

print (pd.Series(weights))
A    0.1
B    1.0
C    1.5
dtype: float64

df[['A','B','C']] *= pd.Series(weights)
print (df)
         id         A         B         C
0 -0.641314 -0.052651  0.225116 -1.696711
1  0.018321 -0.094473 -0.123334 -1.280034
2  0.703119  0.046886  1.038572 -2.294585
```

And more general solution, thanks [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038369/multiply-two-python-arrays-using-a-lookup#comment75104158_44038883) and [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038369/multiply-two-python-arrays-using-a-lookup/44038883?noredirect=1#comment75104904_44038883):

```
df[list(weights)] *= pd.Series(weights)
print (df)
         id         A         B         C
0 -0.641314 -0.052651  0.225116 -1.696711
1  0.018321 -0.094473 -0.123334 -1.280034
2  0.703119  0.046886  1.038572 -2.294585
```

Comment: Yes... this is your answer.  Keeping it generalized `df[list(weights.keys())] *= pd.Series(weights)`

Comment: Very nice, but you should use `list(weights)` instead of `list(weights.keys())`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a terse way, if it tickles your fancy:

```
In [11]: df.assign(**{"{}_product".format(cl): val*df.loc[:,cl]
    ...:               for cl, val in weights.items()})
Out[11]:
         id         A         B         C  A_product  B_product  C_product
0 -1.893885  0.940408  0.841350 -0.669378   0.094041   0.841350  -1.004067
1 -0.526427  0.472322 -0.546121  0.201615   0.047232  -0.546121   0.302423
2 -0.450193 -0.422066  0.564866  1.866878  -0.042207   0.564866   2.800318
```

Or this, if you want to replace the data:

```
In [13]: df.assign(**{cl: val*df.loc[:,cl]
    ...:                for cl, val in weights.items()})
Out[13]:
         id         A         B         C
0 -1.893885  0.094041  0.841350 -1.004067
1 -0.526427  0.047232 -0.546121  0.302423
2 -0.450193 -0.042207  0.564866  2.800318
```

This results in a new data frame, and does not work in-place.

Answer (score 2):

This accommodates non-overlapping keys in both dataframe and dictionary

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])    
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(3,4),
    columns='id A B C D'.split()
)

weights = dict(A=.1, B=1., C=1.5, D=2.)

df

         id         A         B         C
0 -2.129724 -1.268466 -1.970500 -2.259055
1 -0.349286 -0.026955  0.316236  0.348782
2  0.715364  0.770763 -0.608208  0.352390
```

**Note:** `df` has `id` where `weights` does not.  `weights` has `D` where `df` does not.  This solution, only modifies the columns that overlap.  And, it's pretty succinct.

```
df.update(df.mul(pd.Series(weights)).dropna(1))
df

         id         A         B         C
0 -2.129724 -0.126847 -1.970500 -3.388583
1 -0.349286 -0.002696  0.316236  0.523173
2  0.715364  0.077076 -0.608208  0.528586
```